# Amazon EC2 instance : Cannot create temp file for here document. No space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mean-stack

When I log in my system I get this.

> System load:  0.0               Processes:           106
>       Usage of /:   99.7% of 7.74GB   Users logged in:     0

what should I do ? Should I remove the files or should I upgrade the storage?

Comment: do you have any extra files?  i'd start with /var/log/httpd and see if anything is extra in there.

Comment: When I enter the command df -h , this is the result I get.

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            996M   12K  996M   1% /dev
tmpfs           201M  352K  200M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.8G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           1001M     0 1001M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user`

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question is probably too general to answer. Can you afford to upgrade the storage? What files are taking up space? You need to figure this out... which probably means rewriting your question. See [help/on-topic]. This question may also be more appropriate for ServerFault.

Comment: I can afford to upgrade the serve. Just wanted to know if there is any other solution, because the file which is taking up most of space is required and I cannot delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Create an AMI of your instance, launch a new EC2 instance using that AMI and then choose to use a bigger EBS volume.
- create a new EBS volume, attach it to the instance, format it, mount it and then move part of your files there.